# Dijkstra's Algorithm for graph structure

Tags: c++, graph, dijkstra

I'm currently trying to learn some graph theory online and from a friend and he's had me working with a specific structure of graph, I now want to implement Dijkstra's algorithm using the struct but i cant figure out how to. I understand the on-paper theory of Dijkstra but cannot interpret it into code

Below is the header file, used to define the graph

```
typedef struct edge {
    int to_vertex;
    float weight;
} Edge;

typedef struct edgeNode {
    Edge edge;
    struct edgeNode *next;
} *EdgeNodePtr;

typedef struct edgeList {
    EdgeNodePtr head;
} EdgeList;

typedef struct graph {
    int V;
    int *vertex_types;
    EdgeList *edges;
} Graph;
```

Comment: Seems like you're reading a `C` book or material instead of one geared to `C++`.  There is no need for `typedef struct` in C++, just `struct`.  Second, those `structs` are nothing more than `std::list` and `std::vector`.

Comment: [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac00053936b9f910).  This is what it would look like if you used C++ and the standard library.